# How to only keep the rows of pyspark dataframe with the highest value of a column for every user(another column)?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe-

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("u1", "india", 10),
    ("u1", "australia", 12),
    ("u2", "usa", 14),
    ("u2", "nepal", 7),
    ("u3", "england", 13),
    ("u4", "japan", 15),],
    ['user_id', 'place', 'price'])

df.show()
```

Output-

```
+-------+---------+-----+
|user_id|    place|price|
+-------+---------+-----+
|     u1|    india|   10|
|     u1|australia|   12|
|     u2|      usa|   14|
|     u2|    nepal|    7|
|     u3|  england|   13|
|     u4|    japan|   15|
+-------+---------+-----+
```

I only want to keep the rows with highest **price** column for every **user_id**

The desired output should look like-

```
+-------+---------+-----+
|user_id|    place|price|
+-------+---------+-----+
|     u1|australia|   12|
|     u2|      usa|   14|
|     u3|  england|   13|
|     u4|    japan|   15|
+-------+---------+-----+
```

How do I get achieve this?

Comment: what if 2 places with same price which is the highest? do you want both or just one of them?

Comment: i want to keep one of them, anyone would do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using group by and joining with the table to get the place. Groupby, in my experience, get's better performance than window:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df2 = df.groupby("user_id").agg(f.max("price").alias("price"))
df2 = df2.join(df.dropDuplicates(), ["user_id", "price"])

df2.show()
```

Comment: which join is this?

Comment: This will return multiple ids if there are multiple maximum prices

Comment: @mck yes, it's solved deleting duplicates.

Comment: Doing a group by and a join is suboptimal compared to getting the row number and filtering using the row number. That's because joins are expensive. I do not understand why this answer is accepted. @n0obcoder

Comment: @mck I have experienced in the past performance issues with windows. My method also avoids filtering and, in spark 3.0, with AQE and other improvements, join operations have better performance.

Comment: I disagree. Joins have a time complexity of O(N log N), while filters and windows are O(N). Joins are almost always slower than windows or filters. It has nothing to do with AQE.

Answer (score 4):

Assign a row number to each row in each partition, and filter those with row number = 1

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'rn',
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('user_id').orderBy(F.desc('price')))
).filter('rn = 1').drop('rn').orderBy('user_id')

df2.show()
+-------+---------+-----+
|user_id|    place|price|
+-------+---------+-----+
|     u1|australia|   12|
|     u2|      usa|   14|
|     u3|  england|   13|
|     u4|    japan|   15|
+-------+---------+-----+
```